# How to add photo from gallery in Image with Xam.Plugin.Media?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have in my XAML the Image tag and in source a Binding SelectedImage. In the ViewModel I want to have the logic to add the image, but with my current code it does not insert the photo. Enter the gallery but when choosing the image do not show it.

This is my actual code:

MainPage.xaml:

```html
  <Image HeightRequest="50"
         Source="{Binding SelectedImage}"
         WidthRequest="50" />
```

ViewModel.cs:

```
 string selectedimage;
    public string SelectedImage
    {
        get => selectedimage; set
        {
            selectedimage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


 async void insertImage()
    {

        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
        {
            return;
        }

        var mediaOptions = new PickMediaOptions()
        {
            PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium
        };
        var selectedImageFile = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(mediaOptions);

        if (SelectedImage == null)
        {
            return;

        }
        SelectedImage = Convert.ToString(ImageSource.FromStream(() => selectedImageFile.GetStream()));

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use the `Path` property of `MediaFile`

```
// this code does not do anything useful
SelectedImage = Convert.ToString(ImageSource.FromStream(() => selectedImageFile.GetStream()));

// do this instead
SelectedImage = selectedImageFile.Path;
```